# Does Linux support parallel swap in and out for a single process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, swap

**Problem:**

It is dedicated network topology, memory swapping (many GBs) is done via network in a kernel module. The goal is utilization (as much as possible) of network bandwidth (currently 10Gbps).

**Questions:**

Does Linux swapping mechanism retrieve and store a block of memory **sequentially** (page by page) for a particular process?

Is there a difference between memory swap in and out for a single and multi-threaded process ?

Does page-cluster applicable for this case (swap in and out)?

Comment: The close vote is mysterious to me, I find it a very interesting, high quality question. I you would vote to close, please leave a comment on the reason, I am ready to fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Linux swapping mechanism retrieve and store a block of memory
>   sequentially (page by page) for a particular process?

Regarding swapping:

I'am not sure what are you asking about, but i guess the answer is - no. It uses LRU policy to swapout inactive pages.

Regarding unswapping:

It is invoked by page fault.

> Is there a difference between memory swap in and out for a single and
>   multi-threaded process ?

No.

> Does page-cluster applicable for this case (swap in and out)?

Yes that is called readahead, when page fault is occured, usually the cluster of pages is loaded back to memory, but this could be configured.

Regarding network swap and related solutions:

[NSWAP](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/papers/europar03.pdf)

[NFS](http://rom-o-matic.net/etherboot/etherboot-4.6.12/contrib/nfs-swap/nfs-swap.html)

[NBD](http://nbd.sourceforge.net/)